# unable to install jenkins

Tags: jenkins, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/jenkins/packages/jenkins-2.387.2-1.1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID ef5975ca: NOKEY

i am using vagrant and virtual-box for centos VM
i used below command to install the jenkins

```bash
yum update -y
curl --silent --location http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
yum install java-11* -y
yum install jenkins -y
```

Answer (score 5):

They key you are importing with

```
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
```

might be the problem. According to the [Jenkins stable release page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#long-term-support-release-3), the key name is different:

```
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
```